# Oracle ODBC how to check default connection attributes

Tags: oracle, attributes, odbc

I have an application that connect to Oracle DB using oracle-instantclient11.2-odbc-11.2.0.4.0-1 driver in unix. 
The odbc.ini is setting only the below attributes;

- Driver
- DSN
- ServerName
- UserID
- Password

when I test connection failure with network drop to the remote db server while executing query, it takes 17 minutes for application to detect the network drop and exit executing the query.

Query timeout or connection timeout not specified for the application.

Where can I find the default settings values that sets the connection_timeout/lock_timeout for oracle odbc connection in unix.

I'm also unsure which default setting would be triggering the above behavior.

Comment: Check [Using the Oracle ODBC Driver](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_odbc.htm#ADFNS1183)

Comment: You may check also content of your `sqlnet.ora` file, see[Parameters for the sqlnet.ora File](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/sqlnet.htm#NETRF006)

Comment: Thank you!! the settings were in 'sqlnet.ora'. 

I wanted to set Query timeout for my application so if execute time exceeds the limit, the application should disconnect. But found out that Query timeout do not work for oracle-odbc-11.2.0.4 in unix. 

was not able to find a default configuration that enable disconnect after 17 minutes. may be this is set in database server which I have no access. 

But in sqlnet.ora configurations found the below attributes which does the work. 

SQLNET.SEND_TIMEOUT & SQLNET.RECV_TIMEOUT can configure the timeout for both client/server side connection.